# Spring Data Projection size()

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-hateoas

Is there a way to return the size of a collection via rest api projection?

Consider this example:

The data:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class MyData {
    // id 
    // ...

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "mydata")
    private final Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
    // getters/setters ...
}
```

the repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface MyDataRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyData, Long> {
}
```

the projection:

```
@Projection(name = "short", types = {MyData.class})
public interface MyDataProjection {
    // neither of those work
    // @Value("#{target.getUsers().size()}")
    @Value("#{target.users.size()}")
    Integer nrUsers();
}
```

I want to get the number of Users in a MyData-Object returned via REST api.

For example: `my-domain/my-service/mydatas/123/?projection=short`

should return:

```
{
    "nrUsers": 4;
    ...
}
```

Is it possible anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naming convention ist to start with a "get" since the attributes of the projection are methods, not fields. So this works:

```
@Value("#{target.users.size()}")
Integer getNrUsers();
```

(instead of the previous "nrUsers()")